# Can we set a different app.html template for Nuxt a specific Layout or Page

Tags: nuxt.js

I'm looking for a way where I can have a different Nuxt `app.html` page for a specific Layout or Page

For example:

- Layout `/layouts/default.vue` inherits `/app.html`, while `/layouts/new.vue` inherits `/app-new.html`
- Or, Page `/pages/_.vue` inherits default `/app.html`, and `/pages/new.vue` inherits `/app-new.html`.

Comment: What's the use case? A layout should be enough here.

Comment: @kissu we'd like to do have different <head> elements